# How to extract adjacent rows?

Tags: pandas

I have the code below which extract all the rows and columns which contains the string opened.

```
opened =  door[door.Text4.str.contains('opened')]
```

In addition to the above i also need to extract the next row.

```
    A     Text4   C   D
5  foo    opened  0   0
6  bar            1   2
7  bar    closed  3   6
8  foo            6   12
9  foo    opened  7   14
10 foo            7   14
```

so i will end up with a data frame with

```
5  foo    opened  0   0
6  bar            1   2
9  foo    opened  7   14
10 foo            7   14
```

How can i acheive this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select the adjacent row containing `'opened'` with [`shift(1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html), which select the adjacent line. To select both the one containing `'opened'` and the adjacent one, you can use the operator `|`

```
opened = door[door.Text4.str.contains('opened') | door.Text4.str.contains('opened').shift(1)]
```

Result:

```
      A   Text4   C     D 
5   foo  opened   0     0 
6   bar           1     2 
9   foo  opened   7     14 
10  foo           7     14
```